# Как программно получить доступ к содержиму клетки таблицы?

Tags: c#, framework, wpf

в Grid есть много столбцов и строк и в каждой клетке понапиханы разные контролы. Мне нужно по номеру строки и столбца получить доступ к соответствующим конролам и помнять их стиль - цвет заливки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как то сдлеать?(С#) Так же нужно менять местами контролы т.е. в коде С# менять их Column и Row, только как к этим свойствам добраться из элемента я незнаю....?

Comment: Вы хотите программировать на WPF как будто это WinForms: непосредственно манипулирую контролами. Это технически возможно, но _очень_ неудобно, и противоречит духу WPF.

Потратьте время и освойте MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, прислушайтесь к совету [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd).

а по сабжу, сделайте что-то вроде

```
DataControlFieldCell cell = your_grid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex];
var control = cell.FindControl("control_name");
//то, что нужно сделать с контролом
//обновите грид
```